# Why Wordpress isn't and/or can't be domain agnostic

Tags: migration, domain

Can someone please run this down for me?

**EDIT:** Ok, I should've been more precise with my question, so I'll rephrase:
Why did the Wordpress devs choose to store everything including the domain everywhere and not just include it on the fly, marking internal and external links as such.
Beside the fact that migrating any install is not just a simple matter of a search-replace, as one must take into account serialized entries, this makes it difficult even to develop on a stack that requires one to access via a port like 8080, as it too must be added to the domain in the database(think Vagrant).

Don't get me wrong, I'm sure they had their reasons and I trust that they made the right choice, but I would like a rundown of the reasons and maybe pros/cons of going this route.

Comment: hmmm, who said such a thing?  please edit the question and be much more specific in what is it that you mean.

Comment: I think you are asking why you can't simply move WP to a new domain and have it "just work". If that is the case, there are a few reasons, mostly having to do with the large variety of setup/configuration options and plugin/theme developers not considering those options when building their product. Not having the URL saved in the DB would require relative links, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18516783) for more on  why WP chooses not to use them.

Comment: @DaveLak, that answer why it is like it is, not why can't it be different, to which the answer is that it can

Comment: @MarkKaplun I was just about to say that. One of the reasons that crossed my mind was some sites having different values in `WordPress Address` and `Site URL`, which may cause issues if the WordPress itself just fills them out automatically.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Well the title of this question is "Why Wordpress _isn't and/or can't_[...]" so yes, the linked answer addresses the isn't part. The can't is very dependent on an individual's particular case, i.e. will their theme or plugins break with relative URLs so I'm not sure there can be a definitive answer there.

Comment: @DaveLak, the only part of wordpress which is not "domain agnostic" (whatever that actually means) is URLs inserted in a content, which are usually very easy to convert to urls in different domain, if all you change is the domain name. there are probably several plugins that do it or something like it

Comment: @MarkKaplun, Fair enough, I concede. Without a more specific question there is no way to provide a "correct" answer; that's why I'm in the comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is an old one, but if you happened to stumble on this one, here are my two cents:

**THIS IS A VERY VALID QUESTION.**

A Wordpress philosopher may give a better view and answer. But here is what I know by experience.

Many people don't understand this question. Because most of the developers use wordpress for a single website and do it from scratch.
Development from scratch meaning: Install wordpress, set the domain, install plugins etc an soforth.

But the ones who need to change the domain or migrate have problems. These are the ones that do it on the localhost and then upload it to the server, or move a site from one domain to another. They have to replace the sitename in the code (if the code has `defines`) and database. In code one way of making it domain agnostic is to add the following lines in the `wp-config.php` file:

```
$url = (function(){
    $u = parse_url(
        ($_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] ?? ((strtolower(($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ?? 'off') ?: 'off') === 'off') ? 'http' : 'https'))
        .'://'
        .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
        .$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    );
    return $u['scheme'].'://'.$u['host'].'/'.(trim(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),'/\\') ?: '');
})();
define('WP_HOME',       $url);
define('WP_SITEURL',    $url);
```

Even then I have had some Wordpress installations hiccup. WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL don't really seem to get respected.

However, The authentic point for the domain seems to be the database. The first two records in the wp_options (option_name `'siteurl'` and `'home'`).
Changing these may solve your issue for fresh or simple wordpress sites.

Wordpress also provides name change in is setting page - I don't understand how this works as it is a chicken and egg issue... (do you move the site first and then change the setting name or viceversa).

In the database, If lucky you only have to do it in the primary db records (the two places mentioned above) or few other places based on plugins. You can directly do this in the db's exported '.sql' file and import it back into the db. But if the sites have plugins (non domain agnostic ones) that store data by url in the database, then replacing becomes hell. This is because sometimes the urls are saved in serialized php objects and you can't just find-replace the value unless you unserialize them, change the values and serailize them back to the database again.

So to do this developers use plugins that do the migration. Some of them are so bloated (heavy) with features and code that the closest metaphor I can come up is - *nuking the sparrow*. And they leave a lot of residue in the database even after you uninstall them. Even after this they sometimes miss database url instances of the old urls.

-- this so far is my rant.

In software engineering two main styles (architectures) still hold value -the Harvard and Von-Neumann. I'll call them the H-Style and V-Style for brevity. Though this was initially meant for processors the philosophy holds in web development as well.

A little bit of my opinion on these styles:

Simply put - The V-style mixes code and data, The H-style keeps them separate. In web development the benefit for H-style is that, to create another instance of the software we just need copy the code as is and use another dataset. If it is on the same server then we don't even need to copy the code - we just need to point to the right dataset when the code executes. This way you can host hundreds of sites on the same server with one set of code files.

H-style has another advantage. Say you are working on a local system and you made changes to the code. You only need to just drop the code on the server in the right folder and your website changes.

H-style is one of the reason why it is important to have all our data in the db. But then there are 'files' used as data and you have to save them in a folder. Here you need to work out the right isolation methodology.

Most web frameworks don't fully implement this style (ie. clearly isolating Functionality from Data).

But then there is another tier for the H-style (it is the environment and configuration part of the data). Mingling env/cfg with regular data is equally awful as mingling data with code.

Now, Wordpress is built in H-style as far as you take a generic view. But There is always a threat of code and data mingling in Plugins. In addition the env/cfg isolation of Wordpress is not great. And so wordpress fails to be domain agnostic.

In a domain agnostic code once you have the database credentials - you just drop the code in any appropriate folder. If  you want to move it... again copy the code, go to the appropriate folder on the new server and just drop the code, as required change the db credentials - no changing urls in the code.

PHP easily caters to this... It is the frameworks that have to make use of it.